# Get File name shared over Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to get the filename and path which has been sent over bluetooh ? That means start a service when file is being sent over bluetooth.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the path of the file on the recieving device or the sending device?

Comment: sending and receiving both that maintain a log of files transferred over Bluetooth like call log.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible.

The above answer has some great info.

If you want checkout my github project that allows you to pair and send messages to an Arduino Micro Controller over bluetooth. My project is designed to control relays but may help you.

[find here](https://github.com/bigamil/RetroRat/blob/master/gen/com/retrorat/v1/MonitorActivity.java)

Thanks Enjoy

Comment: actually i want file path which transferred over Bluetooth i.e. if a file is being sent or received then the i want to save that file name and path and maintain a log of that files.